# KVM that supports dual (or even triple) monitors, 3 USB inputs for two machines

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a KVM switch that can support multiple HDMI monitors with at least 1900 x 1200 resolution.

This KVM will be connected to a docking station on a laptop running Ubuntu and desktop computer running Windows 10 Professional.

I need the following things to be possible:

- Minimum of two monitors needs to be shared via the KVM. Support for a third monitor would be nice but is not required. Monitor input is HDMI for both the desktop and the laptop docking station.
- The KVM needs to seamlessly support a USB keyboard input, USB mouse input and a USB Headphone/Microphone.
- Support for more than two devices would be nice, but is not required.
- The ability to switch between devices without physically touching the KVM would be nice. I'd like to just bury the KVM behind the monitors/under the desk. However, if soft key switches aren't possible on both Windows/Linux, I can live with positioning the KVM so that I can press the proper button.
- I'd like the KVM to not interfere with gaming when under Windows.

My budget is flexible.

Comment: Are you looking to control 2computers/2monitors with single keyboard and mouse?   Or are you looking to control 2 computers with single keyboard and mouse AND single monitor?

Comment: Two computers with two monitors using a single keyboard and mouse

Answer (score 3):

A quick shot at Google using "multi-monitor kvm" search found a company with the features you've noted. Good thing your budget is flexible.

Dual monitor systems appear to be much more economical than triple (in progress, per one site) or quad.

[KVM Switches Online](http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/dual-monitor-hdmi-kvm.html) does a great job of categorizing the products available, specifically in this case, allowing you to pick HDMI for dual or quad monitors. [One of the switches](http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/sv340h.html) supports USB 3.0 while the other list as USB 2.0 only. The USB 3.0 unit is listed as a hub, but the image of the front shows 3 ports. The rear of the unit has 2 USB ports marked for keyboard and mouse.

[image: KVM front image]

[image: back of kvm]

I should read your question before I hit the submit button. The device listed supports 4k video resolution as well as audio switching. The information leads me to believe that the switched-off unit gets muted, which is as it should be.

A reference is made in the PDF for the product of hot-key switching but no specifics are available.

As is typical of these products, cables are purchased separately. It appears that these units do not require proprietary cables.

The Q/A section of the site suggests to a user that if the above item is inappropriate, to purchase a [different (USB 2.0 version)](http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/uhdn-4p-duo.html) instead. It appears to be nearly the same cost, but with more USB ports on the panel.

Comment: "Good thing your budget is flexible." Haha. Wow. I suppose I should put an upper limit. I guess I wasn't expecting these to be that expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to my comment, I would highly recommend [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy).

I use this product so much. I go back and forth between two monitors side by side with Ubuntu box on one, and Windows on the other. I also slide over and control my macbookpro that sits next to the three.  All with a single keyboard and mouse.

Much cheaper than a KVM and better functionality in my opinion...like copy/pasting across machines...

Comment: The Synergy software is interesting, but it requires each monitor to be connected to its respective machine and doesn't appear to take into the question's requirement of multiple monitors on one/all computers. Despite being an incorrect answer to the question, I didn't downvote.

Comment: I asked the OP a question in comments to clarify before posting @fred_dot_u.  His response was, "Two computers with two monitors using a single keyboard and mouse."  This is why I made the post.

Comment: That clarification seems to allow for some ambiguity in the original question. Typically, a multi-monitor reference means more than one monitor on a single computer. With a KVM, it then implies two monitors for each selected computer. Your question in comments does not appear on my screen, nor does his answer.